# iPhone SDK: How to make 3hg app iPad Compatible?

Tags: iphone, ipad

From Apple Review Guidelines

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

I tried running my app on the iPad simulator. I thought it would be centered in the iPad screen but it was instead in the upper left hand corner. The size that of an iPhone app. Is that typical.

My questions:

a.) Why would the main view be located in the upper left hand corner?
b.) Is there anything special I need to do to an iPhone app to make it pass the above rule. At this time, we are not ready to release an iPad version.

Answer (score 0):

That is strange indeed. Did you try testing it on an iPad device?

Comment: Not on device, only simulator. I think it may have looked centered on the simulator until I made it a Universal App.

Comment: Oh that is something you should have mentioned earlier. Universal binaries are handled differently. If your app is purely iPhone, it can still run on an iPad as you expect it to (at the center with a 1X/2X button to shrink/magnify it). Universal binaries have a shared application delegate that, depending on the device you're on, loads up the iphone app delegate or the ipad app delegate. Though you're issue is not something I have tested or come across, I'm still fairly sure that once you make a universal binary, you do need to specify behavior for different devices.

Comment: Try going back to a purely iPhone build and try running it on the iPad simulator.... it should work as you want it to. Use the universal binary when you're ready to port it to the iPad.

Comment: I went to Target->Targeted Device Family and changed it to iPhone only. Still the app is anchored in the upper left corner. What I am missing?

Comment: You need to roll back from a universal build to an iphone build. Whatever the process was that you undertook to convert your build from an iphone to a universal build, you need to reverse it. simply changing the targeted device family wont do. Could you provide a more detailed explanation of the environment you've set up? You ARE running a universal build right? How many app delegate files does your project have?